# How can I make a slider like in the image? Scrollable and with text and images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a slider with a scrollable right-justified image and text like in the image, how can I do this? https://prnt.sc/26mtj6v

Comment: Hello, could you be more explicit on what you wish to do, maybe do a drawing or something alike ? If you want to place text over an image you will need to use position and z-index properties. For a scrollable area, you will need a container with a set width/height and add a overflow-x: scroll (for horizontal, example).

Comment: I am sending a sample site and picture, you can check it. The image I sent has a scrollable image and a box section for text. Half of the 2nd image will be visible and when you slide to the left in the slider logic, 2 images will come to the front and the text inside the box will change.

https://prnt.sc/26mtuw6

Although not exactly the same, our latest project section on this site is an example http://paul-themes.com/html/liarch/home-default.html

Answer (score 0):

I am sending a sample site and picture, you can check it. The image I sent has a scrollable image and a box section for text. Half of the 2nd image will be visible and when you slide to the left in the slider logic, 2 images will come to the front and the text inside the box will change.

https://prnt.sc/26mtuw6

Although not exactly the same, our latest project section on this site is an example
http://paul-themes.com/html/liarch/home-default.html

Comment: It's best if you edit and post an UPDATE of your initial question rather than an answer, on StackOverflow :) 
Don't hesitate to do so and take-out this answer. Keep us updated of your work

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make a design like the img below :

[image: objective]

---

For the images of my code below, I'm using Bootstrap 5.1.3 (the class names are mostly from the framework)

**1)** you will need to use some `display: flex` on a container in order to have elements in a row and next to each other (create it in your CSS to use that, if you're not using the Bootstrap Framework). Also, add a `width:100%` on that container in order for it to take the whole space (it's the `w-100` class from Bootstrap, or else, add it in your personnal CSS - here 100% is 100% of body)

**2)** you will need to make that container scrollable with a `overflow-x:scroll`

**3)** you will need to create a block (div) for your title and paragraph that needs to be in `position: absolute` and give it `top/bottom/right/left` coordinates

**5)** you will need your container to be in `position: relative`, so the title/paragraph (step 3) is placed depending on the container

**6)** you will need to give your imgs a `width` sufficiently big enough for the scroll to actually start working (you need the elements inside your container to be larger than the container's total width so it becomes scrollable)

---

This is a quick example I made :

[image: example]

---

Here is the code of my example

**HTML :**

[image: HTML]

**CSS :**

[image: CSS]

Comment: Hello,

I'm doing the same, but it doesn't work, can you post the exact codes? When we do it as you conveyed, it is like in the photo.

https://prnt.sc/26n1csw

Comment: Hello @Dijivo, I updated my answer. I was using Bootstrap Framework v.5.1.3 
I add details on step (1) for you to do it without the framework. Keep us updated